# Pugpig framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I have an app with Pugpig framework and this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KGLocalFileDataSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SolitairViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My arhitecture is armv7 arm64.

If I delete arm64 it's working , but when i submit the app on itunes connect it's invalid binary.

And i was trying to change my pugpig framework and i get this :

```
O

BJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Pugpig
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      -[KGFacebookSharingImplementation shareFromViewController:completionHandler:] in Pugpig
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[KGTwitterSharingImplementation shareFromViewController:completionHandler:] in Pugpig
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      -[KGDocumentCache unzipURL:forDocument:] in Pugpig
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[KGDocumentCache unzipURL:forDocument:] in Pugpig
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      _unzReadCurrentFile in Pugpig
  "_htmlEntityLookup", referenced from:
      -[NSString(KGAdditions) stringByStrippingHTML] in Pugpig
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _unzReadCurrentFile in Pugpig
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _unzCloseCurrentFile in Pugpig
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in Pugpig
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[KGDocumentCache unzipURL:forDocument:] in Pugpig
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[KGDocumentCache unzipURL:forDocument:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlCopyNode", referenced from:
      -[KGOPFItem initWithPackage:node:query:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser nodeFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:
      -[KGAtomEntry attributesForNodeFromQuery:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringsFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser dictionaryFromQuery:keyFromAttribute:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser dealloc] in Pugpig
  "_xmlFreeNode", referenced from:
      -[KGOPFItem dealloc] in Pugpig
  "_xmlNodeGetContent", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringsFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser dictionaryFromQuery:keyFromAttribute:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlNodeListGetString", referenced from:
      -[KGAtomEntry attributesForNodeFromQuery:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser initWithData:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlStrcmp", referenced from:
      -[KGAtomEntry deletedEntry] in Pugpig
  "_xmlXPathEvalExpression", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser nodesFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser nodeFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser dealloc] in Pugpig
  "_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:
      -[KGPugpigPackageDocumentType document:didFinishDownloadingSourceURL:withResponse:userInfo:] in Pugpig
      -[KGAtomFeed dealloc] in Pugpig
      -[KGOPFPackage dealloc] in Pugpig
      -[KGAtomEntry categoriesWithScheme:] in Pugpig
      -[KGAtomEntry attributesForNodeFromQuery:] in Pugpig
      -[KGNCXFile initWithContentsOfURL:] in Pugpig
      -[KGXMLDOMParser stringFromQuery:onNode:] in Pugpig
      ...
  "_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser initWithData:] in Pugpig
  "_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:
      -[KGXMLDOMParser registerNamespacePrefix:forURL:] in Pugpig
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a more recent version of the `Pugpig.framework`. Version 2.4 and up supports 64-bit, https://pugpig.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202429446-Release-Notes#2.4.0

---

In answer to your amended question, linker errors are caused by missing dependencies. In the first case it was related to you not having version of Pugpig with a 64-bit slice, in the latter case it relates to missing frameworks/libraries in your target's build settings. Specifically in your case you need to add

```
-lz -lxml2 -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework Social
```

to your target's build settings under "Other Linker Flags".

If you search for missing symbols, you will generally find existing answers for each and everyone of them. For example see [`_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14133153/344544) or [`_xmlCopyNode`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8033179/344544).